# How do I include an ASCII art string literal without getting syntax errors in Python?

Tags: python, ascii-art

Whenever I put an ASCII art in Python code it gives an error from the characters the ASCII art contains.
What do I do?

Here is my code:

```
print('            ____...------------...____
               _.-"` /o/__ ____ __ __  __ \o\_`"-._
             .'     / /                    \ \     '.
             |=====/o/======================\o\=====|
             |____/_/________..____..________\_\____|
             /   _/ \_     <_o#\__/#o_>     _/ \_   \
             \_________\####/_________/
              |===\!/========================\!/===|
              |   |=|          .---.         |=|   |
              |===|o|=========/     \========|o|===|
              |   | |         \() ()/        | |   |
              |===|o|======{'-.) A (.-'}=====|o|===|
              | __/ \__     '-.\uuu/.-'    __/ \__ |
              |==== .'.'^'.'.====|
          jgs |  _\o/   __  {.' __  '.} _   _\o/  _|
              `=====================================')
```

Comment: don't post images of errors or code, also include the code in the post

Comment: Post some example code. it could be as simple as using triple quotes for the art.

Comment: Like the error says, you have an EOL (End Of Line) inside a string literal.  If you use `'''` instead of `'`, a string literal can span multiple lines.

Comment: `r"""..."""` or `r'''...'''` will do the trick, most likely. (In the rare case where your art contains runs of 3 or more quotation marks, you can always read from a file instead of trying to embed the graphic in the script itself.)

Answer (score 4):

You have to paste any ASCII art in a triple-quote raw-string, like this:

```
art = r"""
<paste ascii art here>

"""
```

Comment: thank you !, what does letter r do before the quotes?

Comment: @MalakAnas It is annotation for raw string, and keeps the Python parser from attempting to parse escape codes.  Remove it and you'll see errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `print()` with triplet of double or single quotes:

```
print("""*here is
my favorite
ASCII art*""")
```

or

```
print('''*here is
my favorite
ASCII art*''')
```